# Merging unequal datasets with subgroups

Tags: r, merge, grouping

I have two different datasets of unequal sizes. In addition, one has collapsed subgroups. Here is the data:

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
            ID_name = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "BB", "DD", "DD", "DD"), 
            Volume = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 40L, 20L, 30L, 10L))

df1 = data.frame(ID = c(1L, 2L, 4L), 
                ID_name = c("AA", "BB","DD"), 
                Pop = c(2200L, 3300L, 2000L))
```

I want my results to look like this

```
dfmerged = data.frame(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
                      ID_name = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "BB", "DD", "DD", "DD"), 
                      Volume = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 40L, 20L, 30L, 10L),
                      Pop = c(2200L, 2200L, 2200L, 3300L, 3300L, 3300L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L))
```

Does dplyr has such function? Thanks

Comment: How about `left_join` i.e. `left_join(df, df1)`

Comment: Just like SQL's `join`, datasets do not need to be same length to merge. That is a `cbind` requirement. In fact your merge is one-to-many. Did you try `merge`?

Comment: `merge(df, df1)` should work

Comment: `dfmerged1 = left_join(df, df1, by = c("ID", "ID_name"))` testing:
`identical(dfmerged, dfmerged1) # TRUE`

Comment: Thank you, all! Somehow when i tried on my dataset, it didn't seem to work. Now i tried on a test data and it worked. I spotted the mistake in my old code. Thanks all - you helped me tremendously!